# neo4j spark connector doesn't work correctly

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j

I want to integrate Spark GraphX with Neo4j using [1](https://neo4j.com/product/connectors/apache-spark-connector/)

I tried to follow the steps in [2](https://neo4j.com/developer/spark/quickstart/) but it doesn't work.

What should I do exactly with the neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12-4.0.0.jar file ? I put it in the jar files in the Spark folder.

in bash I write:

C:>Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-shell --jars neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12-4.0.0.jar

Any suggestions please?

**Update no. 1**

I tried this C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-shell --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12:4.0.0

I think it work. but when I want to write the DataFrame to nodes of type Person in spark-shell:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
("John Doe"),
("Jane Doe")
).toDF("name")

df.write.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")
.mode(SaveMode.ErrorIfExists)
.option("url", "bolt://localhost:7687")
.option("authentication.basic.username", "neo4j")
.option("authentication.basic.password", "neo4j")
.option("labels", ":Person")
.save()
```

It raises errors. what should I do?

**Update no. 2**

I follow the steps in the [3](https://medium.com/data-science-school/practical-apache-spark-in-10-minutes-part-7-graphx-and-neo4j-b6b01cffa4fd) and it gives error when entering this:

```
val neo = Neo4j(sc)
```

as follow:

error: not found: value Neo4j

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$SPARK_HOME\bin\spark-shell --conf spark.neo4j.password=<password> --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.4.5-M2
```

instead of:

```
$SPARK_HOME\bin\spark-shell --conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=<password> --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.4.5-M2
```

Just remove the **bolt** word.

**Update**'
Now I want to use the following package:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12:4.0.1_for_spark_3
```

As mentioned in [1](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/releases)

The only one that works is the following (the old version):

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.4.5-M2
```

But using it, the Neo4jGraph.saveGraph is not working. The error is : Writing in read access mode not allowed.

Thanks for your help.